# Use microwave cavity in atomic clock

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, microwaves

In most of the papers regarding atomic clocks, the author talks about a microwave cavity. In this box, all the unwanted frequencies of the electromagnetic radiation are absorbed and the other frequencies are maintained. But how does this work with an atomic clock? In this case, one uses atoms rather than radiation. What is the difference between these applications of the cavity? I thought this might have to do something with the duality between atomic particles and waves, although I couldn't find any sources that could verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At atomic clock works by using a signal generator to produce an EM wave with a frequency matching the caesium hyperfine transition i.e. 9,192,631,770 Hz. The EM wave is sent through a cloud of caesium atoms and the frequency is constantly adjusted to maximise the absorption by the caesium atoms. Keeping the time is just a matter of counting the number of cycles produced by your signal generator and dividing by 9,192,631,770 to get the number of seconds.

So the clock uses a microwave cavity tuned to about 9.192 GHz because that's about the frequency required by the lock. However cavity tuning is not nearly precise enough for timekeeping. So having used the cavity to get an EM wave of about the correct frequency, the frequency is fine tuned to match the absorption line of the caesium atoms. Once this has been done we can start counting cycles to measure time.